# Is this set connected or not?

Tags: connectedness

The set is given: $ \Theta = {(x, y) : (x, y) ∈ Q^c × Q^c}$ where $Q^c$
denotes the set of all irrational numbers. Is this set connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The product $M_1 \times M_2$ is connected iff $M_1$ and $M_2$ are connected.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, the set of rationals (or its complement) is certainly not connected.